# Get data of all registered users in meteor Js

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I want to get the data of all registered users in meteorJS. According to the Doc of meteorJS and stackOverflow, in render function I have tried some methods (the results are as commit showed). I receive only an empty array or subscribtion object when I actually have 2 user accounts in `db.users`:

result of db.users.find()

```
{ "_id" : "uFdKrgSyeBr6msxsH", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-19T12:35:26.930Z"), "services" : { "password" : { "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$.LP2ftnNFDNx1gB7ouaMZ.OwXWLk89iDL6qjOuc.CVebtR/ziiv1K" }, "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [ ] } }, "username" : "AAA" }
{ "_id" : "sJXS2YZ3vENHK2TYT", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-19T12:35:46.266Z"), "services" : { "password" : { "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$TMbeew0aQ/L71YCHjSMoveyf3Kj7Vf0uNnZc7D0OnVtze.ZcuuoE6" }, "resume" : { "loginTokens" : [ { "when" : ISODate("2017-10-19T12:35:46.274Z"), "hashedToken" : "4WpMPUrqydYyKSStCWayBVubNKhgUiLmRio7N1902mg=" } ] } }, "username" : "BBB" }
```

https://github.com/LeMueller/meteor_react_chatroom

Maybe someone knows the problem. Thanks in advance.

code on client:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {DialogServer} from './dialogServer.js';

export default class SendArea extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Find the text field via the React ref
        const text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();

        if(Meteor.userId())

        DialogServer.insert({
            text: text,
            owner: Meteor.userId(),           // _id of logged in user
            username: Meteor.user().username,  // username of logged in user
            createdAt: new Date(), // current time
        });

        // Clear form
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value = '';
    }

    render(){
         let allUsersDate=Meteor.subscribe('allUsers'); //{subscriptionId: "4nHErSSjJLJesWJcq", stop: ƒ, ready: ƒ}
         let allUsersD = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch(); //Array(0)
        return(
          <div>
            <form className="new_message" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <input type='text' ref="textInput" placeholder="message to send"/>
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
     }
}
```

code in server:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.publish('allUsers', function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({},{
        fields:{
            _id:1,
            username:1
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subscribing to your 'allUsers' within your component's render method:

```js
let allUsersDate=Meteor.subscribe('allUsers'); //{subscriptionId: "4nHErSSjJLJesWJcq", stop: ƒ, ready: ƒ}
let allUsersD = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch(); //Array(0)
```

This is not the right way and induces several problems. First of all, you need to check for your subscription, if it's `ready` before you can make use of the data via `Meteor.users.find`.

```js
let allUsersDate=Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
if (allUsersDate.ready()) {
    let allUsersD = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch(); // will return all users
}
```

But even if you would do that as shown above, your `render` method may be called again even before your subscription is ready. The render method is there only for rendering and not data handling.

You should check out how to use `createContainer` to [create a container for Meteor subscriptions](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-create-container#!) and passing this data to your component. This also makes your components more reusable and easier to test (because the required data is injected via props).

Comment: I will try it. Thanks a lot.